# File Upload field with shared files

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, input

I have a form with file upload input `name="image"` and `name="thumb"` ,currently set as a `type="hidden"`.

What I want to do is, when the user selects a file for the image field, the thumb field can share that value. In other words it'll be like a user uploaded the same file twice but in the two seperate fields (image and thumb) but only using one (the image field).

Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: how you trying to upload the file? with JS or server side language?

Comment: @jogesh_pi Server side. PHP

Comment: the simple and cross browser solution is just resize the file with PHP and rename it with the thumb-file name, and the second image remain as it is without change the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File inputs are notoriously hard to interact with programatically, for security reasons. Especially trying to get this to work across many browsers is going to be difficult or impossible.

I'd recommend you handle this server-side by duplicating the file (or the reference to it before you process it) in the handler for the form, if possible.